# Find the kernel of sum of linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Following is the question that I was supposed to answer:
Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ ( the vector space of functions which have all derivatives of all orders)such that $f''+4f=0$ and $f(π)=0$. Find dimension of $W$.
I was wondering if  given two linear transformation $T$ and $U$ acting on a vector space $V$ over field $R$. What could one say about the kernel of $T+U$?

Comment: ??? Denote $F=T+U$ and solve $Fx=0$. Not clearly formulated question. The answer is "Yes, one can", or maybe "It depends".

Comment: The kernel cannot be found in function of the kernels of the summands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing one can really say for your first question is that $\ker T \cap \ker U \subset \ker (T+U)$.

To answer your second question, just solve the differential equation. The solutions are spanned by $\sin(2x), \cos(2x)$. One can easily check that the subspace vanishing at $\pi$ is spanned by $\sin(2x)$, hence the dimension of this subspace is 1.